# How to search for image caption in Wikimedia Commons by API?

Tags: api, mediawiki

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Commons_logo.svg has the caption

"Add a one-line explanation of what this file represents"

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:API/MediaWiki has a few examples how to retrieve such info.

E.g. https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:Commons-logo.svg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=extmetadata

but the caption is not part of it.

How to get the caption via the api ?

P.S.: also "structured data" like that it is a "computer icon" would be nice to be able to retrieve

See https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T250777

Comment: FWIW `Add a one-line explanation of what this file represents` is not the caption, it's the placeholder when there's no caption (in that language).

Answer (score 2):

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&sites=commonswiki&titles=File%3ACommons_logo.svg

seems to be correct approach to get this info